# How to make visual force charting responsive

Tags: apex, visualforce, charts, visualforce-charting

1)We can able to build visual force charting but we need the visual force charting for responsive like different screen size for different devices with same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apex:chart` uses [SVG](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/) to do its drawing using the width and height provided to calculate the locations of the various lines and text. So articles like this [Make SVG Responsive](http://demosthenes.info/blog/744/Make-SVG-Responsive) are relevant.

To see if this "Make SVG Responsive" technique might work I took the first sample controller and page from [Building a Complex Chart with Visualforce Charting](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_charting_example.htm). I then added the suggested styling using a class name `vf-surface` (that "Inspect Element" shows is presently added by `apex:chart` to the `div` surrounding the `svg` element).

The resulting page is this:

```
<apex:page controller="ChartController">
<style type="text/css">
.vf-surface {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
    <apex:chart height="300" width="300" data="{!data}">
          <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="data1" 
            title="Opportunities Closed" grid="true"/>
          <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name" 
            title="Month of the Year">
        </apex:axis>
        <apex:lineSeries axis="left" fill="true" xField="name" yField="data1"
          markerType="cross" markerSize="4" markerFill="#FF0000"/>
   </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

At least on Chrome, this **does** result in the chart being rendered to fit the page size at rendering time.